# Saving Tags in the Database

Tags: php, cakephp, model, tags, tagging

I am trying to implement tags in my application.

```
tags(id, name)
tags_relations (id, tag_id, entity_id)
entity (id, name)
```

here i have a set of 4 tags which i wanna show it as a catgory

> Dish type -> Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Snacks

which are actually tags which can be checked or unchecked for a particular entity.

In another field i allow users to enter tags comma seperated.

I just want to knw which is the best way to save it into the database ?

I am using CakePHP framework..

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1034/Saving-Related-Model-Data-HABTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to follow cake standard:

> ```
> tags(id, name)
> tags_entities (id, tag_id, entity_id)
> entities (id, name)
> ```

bake the 3 tables again and cake will automatically assign the correct relationships. The auto-generated code will let you check and uncheck tags. If you want to "allow users to enter tags comma seperated", you'll need to write some more code to handle that.

Comment: this logic code should i place it in the Tags Model or in the controller ? bcos i wanna check if the tag is there fetch the id and insert that else have to insert the tag and get the id and then insert the relationship

Comment: ideally, the model, where you perform all DB operations. The controller simply directs the control flow without knowing about DB details. You can write a method findIDs($tags_str) in Tag model. And call that from saveEntity() in Entity model to get the list of tag ids. In the findIDs() method, you can also have the logic for "insert if not exist"

Comment: @Harshana: You don't need to worry about that, CakePhp handles that automatically. See Juhana's comment on your question, the 2nd link

Comment: @kaklon that's an example of adding ONE new tag, not a comma-separated list and no "insert if not exist" logic though.

Comment: @Anh Pham: that's right, I skipped the comma-separated list. Nevertheless, it will inserts tags only if they don't exists, retreive there id if they do, automatically.

Comment: hmm.. I doubt that. Because the way save() works is, it looks for the id field, if it exists, do an update, if not, do an insert. The example in the second link will definitely do an insert.

Comment: @Anh Pham do i need to pass all the comma separated tags and then get get back and array with the ids ?

Comment: let's say the user enters "tag1, tag2, tag3". Pass that to the findIDs(), in this method, you'll need to check for each tag, if get the id, if it not exist, insert and get last inserted id. Put all these ids in array and return. It might sound like a lot of queries, but it's as optimized as I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

the join table should be named `entities_tags`:

> join table's name needs to include the names of both models involved, in alphabetical order, and separated with an underscore ( _ )